# Execute php script without permission from web

Tags: php, linux, permissions, sudo, raspbian

I'm trying to execute a php script but i'm having this kind of errors:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/sys/class/gpio/export): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/pi/php-gpio/src/PhpGpio/Gpio.php on line 99
Warning: file_put_contents(/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/pi/php-gpio/src/PhpGpio/Gpio.php on line 103
```

I've tried to set up the permission in the $ sudo visudo like this:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: path/to/my/script
```

or

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

but is not working, i'm able to execute this script only with sudo form the command line!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A quick fix for this would be: `sudo chmod 777 /home/pi/php-gpio/src -R` however it is essentially a security leak.

Comment: @dvdciri who is the owner of the file that you are trying to run (ls -l /path/to/file) and what is the file permission as well ?

Comment: Whoops, the argument should actually be `sudo chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/ -R` but still you should find a way to write data as www-data in a specific folder. Change the owner of that directory to www-data with `sudo chown www-data /path/to/folder` and give the owner write permissions.

Comment: Okay guys, first thanks for the help. Second, this is an api and should run from a client. I'm going to set a auth for these API so i don't care about the security..
@AdelBachene the owner is the user "pi"

Comment: @dvdciri and i guess that your php is runing as root user, so you just need the change the file permision to 777 and take care of the security ^^

Comment: @AdelBachene My actual permission of the script are: -rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody pi 216 Jan 10 13:56 index.php, i've tried to change to 777 and always the same error..

Answer (score 0):

If you using in your computer, you must change the default directory permission:

```
$ sudo chmod -R +w /sys/class/gpio/export
```

else if you run code in a server, in server panel and in section files (e.g. CPanel) change permission and add write right.

Another way is running exec() command:

```
<?php
exec('chmod -R +w /sys/class/gpio/export');
?>
```

However, *php* should have exec right and running with root!

Comment: I'm running it on a server as API.. I'll test you advice ASAP. thanks

Comment: I've tested exec('chmod -R +w /sys/class/gpio/export'); and is always not working.
Also this sudo chmod -R +w /sys/class/gpio/export is not working..

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as root if requested), it solves the limitations of exec() and shell_exec(). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('/sys/class/gpio/export');
$return2  = $shell->exeCmd('/sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction');

//the return will be a string containing the return of the command
echo $return1;
echo $return2;
```

In terms of security it is far better than running apache as root, or the wide open sudo permissions in your question. But letting PHP anywhere near root is always tricky.

The project i built achieves a root bash shell in one of 2 ways:

1) You allow apache the right to sudo python.

OR

2) You pass root credentials to the object every time you need a shell with root setup.

Pick your poison. :) Read the documentation.